# Spinner going back of the mat dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, angular-material, angular-material2

We are using progress spinner for every API call. And we registered spinner at the app module level. When we want spinner on dialog the spinner hiding back of the popup.

To fix this we are adding spinner tag in every dialog component HTML. even z index also not working here. we have tried mat progress spinner and other spinners as well but no use.

Can we have a solution for this issue?

Comment: could you please provide stackblitz example ?

Comment: what's the problem with using spinner inside dialog? Anyways, did you try using a z-index above 2000 with a position: absolute

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-co9fxw

Comment: Here it's working. the same thing not working in my application. spinner going back to the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes to the component as it should dynamically create and append to the body element. now this problem has been resolved.

```
const domElem = (this.componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
            .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

        document.body.appendChild(domElem);
```